# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'configId' available as request attribute Jasper Exception

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am developing the spring CRUD application. In my list screen i have a edit button when click on edit button it has to redirect to another page where i have form input fields. The content which i want to edit will be loaded over there.

Here in the jsp i am using

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

when i click on edit icon i am getting this error:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'configId' available as request attribute Jasper Exception
```

This is my update.jsp code

```
 <form:form action="updateContact.do" commandname="FeedUpdate" method="post"></form:form>
                    <div class="small-3 columns">
                     <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Config Id</label>
                     </div>

                    <div class="small-9 columns">
                    <form:input path="configId" readonly="true"></form:input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Feed Id</label>
                    </div>

                    <div id="val" class="small-9 columns">
                    <form:input path="feedId" readonly="true"></form:input>
                    </div>
```

This my Java Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateFeed", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam("key")Integer id)
{
    FeedForm feedForm = new FeedForm();

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("FeedUpdate");

    FeedFormDAO feedFormDAO = new FeedFormDAO();
    feedForm = feedFormDAO.selectFeed(String.valueOf(id));

    mav.addObject("FeedUpdate", feedForm);
    return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if "`configId`" is present as an attribute (along with valid getters and setters) in your `FeedForm .java`